# Oozie: workflow: How to get the last successful action

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to sending an email alert if any action in my oozie workflow fails. How do I get which action got failed or is there any way to see the last successful action name in the workflow DAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to get last "successful" action AFAIK. If you think about it outside specific context for a moment: it's not easy to define "success" considering fork/join, control nodes, etc.

However, once criteria is defined, I guess it's possible to  find last "successful" node using Oozie's REST API. For example, the response of workflow ($OOZIE_URL/v1/job/job_id?show=info) returns a list of actions within workflow. Actions are linked with "transition" field: last action's transition is null, other nodes' transition is their downstream node, etc.

Good luck and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get which action got failed

```
wf:lastErrorNode()
```

In the following Oozie-workflow example snippet , the aforementioned function is used to get the error message of the last failed action:

```
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Action failed, error message: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}</message>
</kill>
```

I'm not aware of any way to get the "last successful action name."

See the [Workflow EL functions section](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.3_Workflow_EL_Functions) of the Oozie Workflow documention for more information on functions such as these.